# How to have &/&amp; in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config

i m passing URl from web config where i need to write
Example ::   URL=http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&rlz=1R2SKPB_enIN332&ei=yktESuLfIIbg7APpquQj&sa=X&spell=1

if i write this url in web.config file i m getting in valid URL.

How to go about it?

Comment: I would suggest being a bit more specific in your question: You're not just trying to add a URL into the web.config, you're trying to add it in a specific place, and based on the comments you've left to other answers, are trying to do something that isn't supported: use the IIS7 Rewrite Module to redirect users from your site to another server.

Answer (score 35):

Make sure it is written using proper Xml encoding (which, amont other things, will replace all '&' characters with '`&amp;`').

This should work well:

```
<add key="uri" value="http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&amp;rlz=1R2SKPB_enIN332&amp;ei=yktESuLfIIbg7APpquQj&amp;sa=X&amp;spell=1" />
```

Comment: lol - answered on the same second.  i've never seen that before!

Comment: i m working on URlRewitting where i had follows Tag:::
<rewrite url="/Googlelog" to"http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&amp;rlz=1R2SKPB_enIN332&amp;ei=yktESuLfIIbg7APpquQj&amp;sa=X&amp;spell=1" processing="stop"/>

I gotting following error:
"http://www.google.co.in/search" is not a valid virtual path

Comment: are you sure you can rewrite to a URL on another server?  if not, rewrite to a page ON your server, and redirect from there...

Comment: i am not sure about this , I will try with u r suggestion

Comment: will u get me answer for this : can we rewrite the URL on another server?

Comment: @jyoti: not sure about that. My spontaneous guess is "no", but I didn't work enough with url rewriting to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 9):

Web.config needs to be valid XML - so replace the & with &amp;.  When you read it from your config u can always convert it back with [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx)

Comment: i alredy tried with this option. replace the & with &amp.
If URL is in followin format it works fine: to="~/content/category.aspx?SID=13" ;;; if URL=http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&rlz=1R2SKPB_enIN332&ei=yktESuLfIIbg7APpquQj&sa=X&spell=1 is not working

Comment: you can extract the URL from your web.config.  and once you have it do you convert the &amp; back to a single '&'?  what is the error you are getting?